# Using another type assignment as a type as function argument?

Tags: typescript

I just stumbled over this syntax

```
const getHeaders = (instant: (arg: string) => string) => [
  {
    label: instant("some string"),
    key: "street",
  },
```

What does the type assignment of instant mean? Are we saying instant is of type (arg: string) ?

Comment: `instant: (arg: string) => string` means that `instant` should be a function with one `argument` which is type of `string` and `return value` of the function also should be type of  `string`. For instance when you would like to use `getHeaders`, you should pass a function as `argument` like this: `myFunc(arg: string) => { return arg; }`. As the consequence, value of `label` is equal to `return value` of `instant` passed method. I don't know you have you tried `C#` or not, But in `C#` it acts like a `delegate`.

Answer (score -1):

The `instant` parameter is of type `(arg: string) => string`. It's a function that takes one parameter named `arg`, of type `string` and returns a `string`.

```
const myInstant = (a: string) => 'example: ' + a;
function anotherOne(a: string) { return a; }
getHeaders(myInstant);
getHeaders(anotherOne);
```